# Unable to output all values in multisearch when using typehead (RunningCoder)

Tags: jquery, html, typeahead

I've spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to extract the values from the input box when using 'RunningCoder' typeahead plugin when using multiselect.

I am able to easily a get a single value (the last one in the box) however cannot get all the values. To get the single value I am using the code below. It creates a global variable (cuisineType) fom the value in the box.

```
callback: {
    onClick: function (node, a, item, event) {
        window.cuisineType = item.cuisineOption
    },
 }
```

I thought something like this might work, based on the recomended onSubmit code. But it doesnt!

```
callback: {
    onClick: function (node, form, items, event) {
        window.cuisineType = JSON.stringify(items)
    },
 }
```

My input boxes don't have individual 'submit' buttons.

**How do I get all the values from the multisearch and output them?**

Thanks so much in advance!

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bc68rae/7/) of my Code.

HTML

```
  <form>
    <div class="questionDiv">
      <label for="searchCusineInput">Question 1</label>
        <div class="typeahead__container">
            <div class="typeahead__field">
                <div class="typeahead__query" id="searchCusineContainer">
                    <input id="searchCusine" class="searchBox" name="hockey_v2[query]" type="search" placeholder="Cusine Search" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="questionDiv">
        <label for="searchRegionInput">Question 2</label>
        <div class="typeahead__container">
          <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query" id="searchRegionContainer">
              <input id="searchRegionInput" class="searchBox" name="hockey_v2[query]" type="search" placeholder="Region Search" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <button type="button" class="submitWelcomeForm" value='Submit'>Submit</button>
    <div class="resultA"></div>
    <div class="resultB"></div>
</form>

<div class="demo"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.submitWelcomeForm', function () {
 $(".resultA").text(cuisineTypeA)
 $(".resultB").text(TypeB)
});

typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
    input: '#searchCusine',
    minLength: 1,
    maxItem: 8,
    order: "asc",
    hint: true,
    searchOnFocus: true,
    blurOnTab: false,
    cancelButton: false,
    multiselect: {
        limit: 10,
        limitTemplate: 'Select 10 cuisines or less!',
        cancelOnBackspace: true,
        cancelButton: false,
    },
    templateValue: "{{cuisineType}}",
    display: ["cuisineType"],
    emptyTemplate: 'No results for {{query}}',
    source: {
        data: [
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
            "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
            "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
            "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",
            "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti"
        ]
    },
    callback: {
        onClick: function (node, form, item, event) {
            $(".demo").text(item.cuisineType + ' Added!')
            window.cuisineTypeA = item.cuisineType
        },
    }
});

typeof $.typeahead === 'function' && $.typeahead({
    input: '#searchRegionInput',
    minLength: 1,
    maxItem: 8,
    order: "asc",
    hint: true,
    searchOnFocus: true,
    blurOnTab: false,
    cancelButton: false,
    multiselect: {
        limit: 10,
        limitTemplate: 'Select 10 cuisines or less!',
        cancelOnBackspace: true,
        cancelButton: false,
    },
    templateValue: "{{cuisineTypeA}}",
    display: ["cuisineTypeA"],
    emptyTemplate: 'No results for {{query}}',
    source: {
        data: [
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
            "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
            "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
            "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
            "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",
            "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti"
        ]
    },
    callback: {
        onClick: function (node, form, item, event) {
            $(".demo").text(item.cuisineTypeA + ' Added!')
            window.TypeB = item.cuisineTypeA
        },
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.typeahead__container, .submitWelcomeForm {margin: 5px}
.typeahead__container {width: 50%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it has been 17 days, will toss out the only clue I have.

https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/397#issuecomment-381190370

This is the closest I came to figuring it out. This is what one person said he did to get it to submit on a normal submit.

> I have added a parallel hidden input field to each multiselect field in order to handle the selections as a native form would on form submission:

I am having the same issue and trying to figure it out as well. Maybe append?

Edit:

I used a version like this to add the tags to a hidden field and then that passed per a normal form without issue

```
callback: {
    onClick: function (node, form, item, event) {
        var input = $("#hidden_field");
        // this is my default for empty to make it easy as I am newb!
        // if it is empty, just throw in the selection
        if (input.val() === "0"){
            input.val(item.cuisineTypeA);
        // if not empty, append to what is already in there
        }else{
            input.val(input.val() + "," + item.cuisineTypeA);
        }
    },
}
```